# Ubuntu 12.10 boots to purple screen after upgrading from 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, dual-boot, upgrade, graphics

I'm new to the whole linux world. I had Windows7, so in order to not to lose it I made a new partition for Ubuntu 12.04.

After the installation everything was good except a huge problem, my lapto has an Intel HD graphics card AND an AMD Radeon HD 6470M but to my surprise I saw the system used the  Intel graphics card whenever I logged into Ubuntu. I searched over the Internet but couldn't get anything.

And now comes The monumental problem, After upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 when I rebooted and selected Ubuntu from Grub mneu, the whole booting procedure stacks every time at the purple screen and never reaches the login screen I don't know what to do  anymore I feel kinda desperate.

Unfortunately I cant provide any more info. because I call myself newbie at the Linux environment. If this whole thing rings any bell , is there any way we can fix this?

Comment: Did you install the propiatery drivers when you were on 12.04?

Answer (score -1):

If you have the media you installed Ubuntu from, insert it into your computer and restart. If you don’t, download a Ubuntu live CD and burn it to a disc or install it on a USB flash drive. You can also download a dedicated Boot Repair live CD

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair boot-repair
```

click recommended repair.
[reference boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)